# Как создать свою ошибку в rules yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как создать ошибку свою в rules() на подобии:

```
 ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255]
```

Comment: Вы хотите правило создать со своими атрибутами на подобии min, max или без них?

Comment: Ну создать правило на подобии есть ли такой id в бд

Comment: Для проверки id в базе можно exists использовать (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#exist) он чем то не подходит?

Comment: Просто нужно сделать прям как по правилам Yii2 записать ошибку в rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимальный пример своего валидатора:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            ['username', 'validatorUsername'],
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function validatorUsername($attribute)
    {
        if (isset($this->username)) {
            if([ВАШЕ УСЛОВИЕ]) {
                $this->addError($attribute, '[ВАШ ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ]');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
['ref', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id',
                'targetClass'=> '\common\models\User',
                'message' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Такого реферала не существует.')
            ],
```

Comment: Какой из ответов отвечает на ваш вопрос наиболее полно? Отметьте его как принятый.